# ID exists jQuery "test" not working

Tags: jquery

OK thought I would be clever... https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/ says you can just do

```
$( "#myDiv" ).show();
```

to see if something exists.

I have text areas that, when added, have IDs message2, message3 etc. I want to remove a button when there is only one textarea. So, at that point, there will be no message2 id (not very elegant structure but it works). So trying to build a hide button function.

```
$("#removeMessage").on('click', function () {
    $(".smhTextArea:last").remove();
    if ($("#message2")){}else {alert("Gone!")};
})
```

The click removes the last textarea as intended but I do NOT get the alert. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
if (!$("#message2").length){ //if there's no #message2
   alert("Gone!")
}
```

It is also there in your [provided link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/).

It's not the way to test whether an element exists or not:

```
$( "#myDiv" ).show();
```

But it's the way to test:

```
if ( $( "#myDiv" ).length ) {
```

Comment: @Babel What does that mean? There's nothing but a selector and Boolean($('#message2')) returns true. Because even there is no element with id message2 it will return an empty object `Object[ ]` So, converting to this will be truthy.

Comment: Bhojendra was just trying to do the clever `$( "#myDiv" ).show();` sort of thing as suggested on the jQuery  site. Yep this is the most elegant version I guess. Just hoped to b e able to spin the other.

Comment: Babel tried      `$(!"#message2").$("#removeMessage").addClass("hidden");` but no joy - ah well

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#message2").length == 0) {
//doesnt exist
}
```

Comment: Miss P thanks - seems I can only tick one answer and ... oh you need the rep so you get it :-) (Even tho Bojendra's was a little more "elegant")